# Can someone help me with how to create effects like Facebook effects on stories on code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to implement a feature where if a user clicks on a reaction, they receive an animation similar to Facebook stories. I have provided HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code for the implementation. The HTML code consists of a container div with reactions represented by emojis. The CSS defines the styling for the reactions and the animation. The JavaScript adds an event listener to each reaction, triggering the animation when clicked.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbSID.png)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.reaction').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
      const bubble = document.createElement('div');
      bubble.classList.add('bubble');
      bubble.textContent = item.textContent;
      item.appendChild(bubble);
      setTimeout(() => {
        bubble.remove();
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
```

```css
.reaction {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .animate {
    animation: popUp 0.5s ease forwards;
  }
  
  @keyframes popUp {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="reaction" id="like"></div>
    <div class="reaction" id="love">❤️</div>
    <div class="reaction" id="wow"></div>
    <div class="reaction" id="haha"></div>
    <div class="reaction" id="sad"></div>
    <div class="reaction" id="angry"></div>
</div>
```

Hi everyone. I want to implement a feature where, if a user clicks on a reaction, they receive an animation similar to Facebook stories. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please describe the animation required. Is it just to scale the emoji or is it also to have it jump up elsewhere and then return?